# index of dropdownlist resets/values are kept on selecteditemchanged

Tags: asp.net, drop-down-menu, indexing

I have to fill some DropDownLists on PageLoad and during the runtime. The second DropDownList is filled if the first calls its `onSelectedItemChanged()` because I have to fill the 2nd ddl depending to the selectedvalue of the 1st ddl. I get the data for the 2nd ddl from a sql query.
Here is my code:

```
private void fill_dropdown_schueler(string klasse)
{
    string query_select = "";
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
    SqlDataReader dr;
    SqlCommand select;
    ArrayList schueler = new ArrayList();

    con.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Projektwoche"].ConnectionString;

    try
    {
        if (con.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
            con.Open();

        /*** Fill DropDownList4 "Schüler" ***/
        query_select = "SELECT [Nachname], [Vorname], [Katalognummer] FROM [Projektwoche].[dbo].[Einträge] WHERE Klasse='" + klasse + "'ORDER BY [Nachname] ASC;";
        select = new SqlCommand(query_select, con);
        dr = select.ExecuteReader();
        int index = 0;
        while (dr.Read())
        {
            schueler.Add((String)dr["Nachname"] + " " + (String)dr["Vorname"] + "  Nr: " + (String)dr["Katalognummer"]);
            kata[index] = Convert.ToInt32((String)dr["Katalognummer"]);
            index++;
        }
        dr.Close();

        DropDownList4.DataSource = schueler;
        DropDownList4.DataBind();

        schueler.Clear();

        con.Close();
    }

    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Label7.Text = e.ToString();
    }
}
```

So I store the values of `Katalognummer]` in the global array `kata[]` so I can access the values of them by the index of the 2nd DropDownList (without doing some more queries).

If i put the values of the array `kata[]` into an Label they are all right but only if i put the `Label.Text = kata[].ToString();` into this function.

This function is called in the `onSelectedItemChanged` method from the first ddl.

If i want to get the values of the array `kata[]` in an other function, all values are 0 and not as i wanted the values i got from the query .

It seems the array `kata[]` gets cleared after this function???

Comment: It's hard to tell what the problem is... there isn't any code illustrated showing how the data's being bound...

Comment: hope its more helpful now

Comment: Yes, thanks.  Is this all happening in the same request?  ASP.NET does not store data across page postbacks automatically.  Also, is kata a global variable?  What else touches the kata variable in your page?